# EF Core to Mysql table binding

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have the following table in MySQL
[image]

When I run the following code in some middleware

```
var apiKeys = _appContext.apikey.ToList();
```

I get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'.

This is my ApiKey class

```
public class ApiKey
{
    public string apikeyid { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string apikey { get; set; }
    public bool isactive { get; set;}
    public bool ispaid { get; set; }
    public bool ismod { get; set; }
    public bool isadmin { get; set; }
}
```

I had this working with a Postgresql db and just moved over to MySQL.  Does this have something to do with going from tinyint (in the db) to bool (in the class)?

I'm using `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.13`

Comment: Yes it does - you are using `bool` but the schema is defined as a mysql `tinyint`

Comment: I believe using an `int` in your model will fix this

Comment: This sounds like a reported bug in MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92987 You could try switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql which is reportedly a lot less buggy.

Comment: Mapping `TINYINT(1)` (aka `BOOL`) to `bool` in C# is a typical practice with MySQL & .NET and Pomelo fully supports it AFAIK.

Comment: I'm getting this issue too. It's obviously a bug in the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore library - it maps database bool types to Int16 types in .NET.

Comment: Using the Pomelo driver worked, thanks guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2 possible options as answered in comments already.

- [Pomelo driver](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) supports bool to int mapping,
- Second option would be using [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), which works with the other driver.

  entity.Property(p => p.isActive).HasConversion< int >();